# Optimizing HTML Parsing in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have some VBA code that makes a request to https://nt3-s.zacks.com/fundamreports/Default.aspx and extracts all the data to a worksheet. My issue is that my parsing technique takes a very long time. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve what the code below does? Maybe I should utilize QuerySelectorAll() or some other method...

```
Sub Financials(ticker, SheetName As String)
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim RP1, RP2, QP1, QP2, QP3, QP4, QP5, QP6 As String
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLRow, HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim r, c, offset, shift As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

shift = 50

' STANDARDIZED FINANCIAL STATEMENTS

' Generate income statements
'============================

XMLPage.Open "Post", "https://nt3-s.zacks.com/fundamreports/Default.aspx", False

' Header
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

' Body Parameters
' Required parameters so every table value can be editted
RP1 = "__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJNDg5NjgzODkyD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIBD2QWBAIPDxAPFgIeB0VuYWJsZWRnZGRkZAITDxAPFgIfAGdkZGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQhidG5FeGNlbHC%2FJVg5ST2AoHtph1XAsQL0bObX"

' String is too long to be typed in one line...
a1 = "%2FwEWdALpx6COCwKm07CqBwKSh%2B%2FQCgL96MW%2BBgLN6MW%2BBgLav7PDDQLCv%2FPADQLNv%2FPADQLcv%2FPADQLfv%2FPADQLev%2FPADQLZv%2FPADQLYv%2FPADQLbv%2FPADQLav%2FPADQLFv%2FPADQLduMOkAwLq0v%2FjCQLq0uO8AQLq0teZCgLq0rvyAwLq0q%2FPDALq0pOoBALq0oeFDQLq0uvhBgLq0p%2BJAwLq0oPiDALX%2B53NDwLX%2B4GmBwLX%2B%2FUCAtf72d8JAtf7zbgBAtf7sZUKAtf7pe4DAtf7icsMAtf7vfIJAtf7oc8CApOYyLkHApOYvBICk5ig7wkCk5iUyAICk5j4pAoCk5jsgQMCk5jQ2gwCk5jEtwQCk5jo3gICk5jcuwoC%2BKHuog0C%2BKHS%2FwYC%2BKHG2A8C%2BKGqtQcC%2BKGeDgL4oYLrCQL4ofbHAgL4odqgCgL4oY7ICAL4ofIkAuW2jIwDAuW28OgMAuW25MUFAsTR38AHAvO744cNAvO7%2F9gFAvO7y%2F0OAvO7p5YHAvO7s6sIAvO7j0wC87ub4QkC87v3hQIC87uD7QcC87ufhggCzpKBqQsCzpKdwgMCzpLp5gQCzpLFuw0CzpLR3AUCzpKt8Q4CzpK5igcCzpKVrwgCzpKhlg0CzpK9qwYCivHU3Q"
a2 = "MCivGg9gQCivG8iw0CivGIrAYCivHkwA4CivHw5QcCivHMvggCivHYUwKK8fS6BgKK8cDfDgLhyPLGCQLhyM6bAgLhyNq8CwLhyLbRAwLhyILqBALhyJ6PDQLhyOqjBgLhyMbEDgLhyJKsDALhyO7ABAL835DoBwL83%2ByMCAL83%2FihAQLnzLDSBAL4zLDSBAL5zLDSBAL6zLDSBAL8zLDSBAL9zLDSBAK3wpPeDgKFwpPeDgKuh8zbAwKhh8zbAwLR2eHwDAKFt7SHCcQGh8eHqGGqe%2F6U9Wz%2FpSk9FF8d"

RP2 = "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" & a1 & a2

' Query Parameters
QP1 = "&tbTicker=" & ticker
QP2 = "&ddBasis=Q"
QP3 = "&ddPeriod=0"
QP4 = "&ddFrom=" & CStr(Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -10, Date)))
QP5 = "&ddTo=" & CStr(Year(Date))
QP6 = "&ddFormType=0"

XMLPage.send RP1 & RP2 & QP1 & QP2 & QP3 & QP4 & QP5 & QP6

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

r = 1
c = 1
offset = 0 * shift

Sheets(SheetName).Select

Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Extract data from table
For Each HTMLRow In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("th")
        Cells(r, c + offset).value = HTMLCell.innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next HTMLCell
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        Cells(r, c + offset).value = HTMLCell.innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next HTMLCell
c = 1
r = r + 1
Next HTMLRow

' Generate balance statements
'======================================
'Request
XMLPage.Open "Post", "https://nt3-s.zacks.com/fundamreports/Default.aspx", False

' Header
XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

QP6 = "&ddFormType=1"

XMLPage.send RP1 & RP2 & QP1 & QP2 & QP3 & QP4 & QP5 & QP6

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

r = 1
c = 1
offset = 1 * shift

'Extract data from table
For Each HTMLRow In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("th")
        Cells(r, c + offset).value = HTMLCell.innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next HTMLCell
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        Cells(r, c + offset).value = HTMLCell.innerText
        c = c + 1
    Next HTMLCell
c = 1
r = r + 1
Next HTMLRow
```

EDIT: I changed the code to include more details about my program. The sub will collect the income statements, balance sheets, cash flows, and other metrics for multiple companies at once. I included a couple of instances of how I'm using the POST method to parse the data.

Comment: if you are calculating with every iteration, you can try adding `Application.Calculation = xlManual` to the beginning of your macro and `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` to the end which would prevent updating calculations after every passing loop.

Comment: Wow thanks! I've got hundreds of thousands of formulas and UDFs feeding off what was being scraped. This literally reduced the time from about 10 min to about 20 sec. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help! I will add it as an answer to help others.

Comment: Could you provide enough to reproduce this as I think I build upon the current answer and maybe we get something even faster. Please also provide what your office version is.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I edited the code in the question to include the details on how I'm parsing the data. There's more being collected but it's roughly the same format as the "Balance Sheet" section with the minor adjustment to form type. I use the latest version of office, which I believe is 2019. Hope this is enough info.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks. What would be an example ticker value?

Comment: Any company ticker traded in the US should work, such as AAPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calculating with every iteration, add `Application.Calculation = xlManual` to the beginning of your macro and `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` to the end which will prevent updating calculations after every passing loop.